# How to create roport in RTC using BIRT on entered data weekly/monthly manner

Tags: birt, rtc

I am new for birt,my problem statement is that,when users add value in particular attribute in RTC work item daily ,then take sum of those all values and show the result on weekly/monthly manner in report using birt

Can anyone have any idea on the same?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more your problem/issue?

Comment: My problem statement is that .suppose in one week i created 10 workitem and in that work work item certain attribute present ,then in birt report take all the sum of that attribute value on that week and show sum only on that week  in report simply means show the result weekly wise

Comment: Ok then sorry I cannot understand. Hope somebody will help you!